# IndentationError: expected an indented block in while loop

Tags: python

I have got this error when I am trying to web scrape from multiple websites

```
import urllib
urls = ["http://google.com","http://cnn.com"]

i=0
n=len(urls)

while i< n:
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
htmltext =htmlfile.read()
print htmltext
i=i+1
```

**Error**:

```
  PS C:\python> python basic1.py
  File "basic1.py", line 9
  htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib 

urls = ["http://google.com","http://cnn.com"]

i=0
n=len(urls)

while i < n:
   htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
   htmltext =htmlfile.read()
   print htmltext
   i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you're not indenting. Python requires strict indenting as code block delimiters. Try this:

```
i=0
n=len(urls)

while i< n:
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext =htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have indentation error, it means, you some sub-block needs to have like 4spaces before it, this is clear in your while code block, this is the correct way:

```
import urllib
urls = ["http://google.com","http://cnn.com"]

i=0
n=len(urls)

while i< n:
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext =htmlfile.read()
    print htmltext
    i=i+1
```